# Probability in a fun game show

Tags: probability

On a game show, the -
 contestants each day can win $1, 000, 000 by correctly guessing an integer between 1 and 100
inclusive (which is chosen randomly each day). Before guessing the contestant can ask one yes/no question of his or
her choice. Monday's contestant asked Is the number 57? and Tuesday's contestant asked ìs the number greater
than 50?. Let P (M) be the probability of Monday's contestant winning and let P(T) be the probability of Tuesday's
contestants winning (assume each contestant properly uses the information gained from the question). Which of the
following is true?
A. P (M)/
P (T)
 <.1 B. 0.1 <
P (M)/
P (T)
< 0.9 C. 0.
9< 
P (M)/
P (T)
< 1.1 D. 1.1 <
P (M)/
P (T)
< 2 E.
P (M)/
P (T)
< 2

Comment: Just so you know, your Erdös number is definitely not zero... unless you are somehow actually Erdös.

Answer (score 2):

If $W$ denotes the winning number then:$$P(M)=P(M\mid W=57)P(W=57)+P(M\mid W\neq57)P(W\neq57)=$$$$1\cdot\frac1{100}+\frac1{99}\cdot\frac{99}{100}=\frac1{50}$$

More directly you could say that Monday's contestant uses the possibility to ask two distinct numbers. If the first happens to be correct already then the asking of the second is virtual.

Further we also find:$$P(T)=\frac1{50}$$This because after answer "yes" as well as answer "no" there is a choice between $50$ equiprobable numbers.

---

**edit** (to give some clarity) concerning monday contestant.

The event $M$ (i.e. the monday contestant wins) can be split up in two mutually exclusive events:

the answer on his question is "yes" and (of course) his guess will be $57$ **or** the answer on his question is "no" and (of course) he guesses a number that differs from $57$ which appears to be the correct number.

In mathematical language this is: $$M=(M\cap\{W=57\})\cup(M\cap\{W\neq57\})$$

Note that $\cap$ corresponds with "and" and $\cup$ corresponds with "or".

If two events $A,B$ are mutually exclusive (i.e. they cannot happen both, or mathematically $A\cap B=\varnothing$ then we have the rule $P(A\cup B)=P(A)+P(B)$ and applying that here we find:$$P(M)=P(M\cap\{W=57\})+P(M\cap\{W\neq57\})$$Now it remains to find the two terms.

If $A,B$ are independent events (i.e. the probability that $A$ happens will not affect the probability that $B$ happens, and vice versa) then we have the rule:$$P(A\cap B)=P(A)P(B)$$

However we cannot apply that here because we are definitely not dealing with events $M$ and $\{W=57\}$ that are independent here!

Then how to find $P(A\cap B)$ if $A,B$ are events that are not independent? For that we use another rule that also results in a multiplication:$$P(A\cap B)=P(A\mid B)P(B)$$

Here $P(A\mid B)$ stands for the probability that event $A$ happens under the condition that event $B$ happens.

Applying that on the first term we find: $$P(M\mid \{W=57\})P(\{W=57\})$$or a bit more shortly written:$$P(M\mid W=57)P(W=57)$$

Now what is the probability that monday wins if $57$ is the winning number? $1$ of course, because the answer on his question has been answered with "yes" and then he simply *knows* that $57$ is the winning number. He will surely guess that number and win. This tells us that $P(M\mid W=57)=1$. Further what is the probability that $57$ is indeed the winning number? $\frac1{100}$ of course because there are $100$ equiprobable candidates. This tells us that $P(W=57)=\frac1{100}$ and we can calculate the first terms as:$$P(M\mid W=57)P(W=57)=1\cdot\frac1{100}=\frac1{100}$$

Now it remains to find the second term which will have the looks:$$P(M\mid W\neq57)P(W\neq57)$$ What is the probability that monday wins if the winning number is not $57$? His question has been answered with "no" and this information tells him that the winning number must be one of the elements of $\{1,2,\dots,56,58,\dots,99,100\}$. They have equal chances so the conclusion is evidently that $P(M\mid W\neq57)=\frac1{99}$. But we must not forgot the other factor: $P(W\neq 57)$, i.e. the probability that the winning card is not $57$ or equivalently the probability that his question is answered by "no". For that we find quite easily $P(W\neq57)=1-P(W=57)=1-\frac1{100}=\frac{99}{100}$. Now we are equipped to find the second term: $$P(M\mid W\neq57)P(W\neq57)=\frac1{99}\frac{99}{100}=\frac1{100}$$This results in:$$P(M)=P(M\cap\{W=57\})+P(M\cap\{W\neq57\})=\frac1{100}+\frac1{100}=\frac1{50}$$

Comment: for tuesday player if the answer is yes then there is only 49 numbers greater then 50 ( 50 is not included) . if No then the numbers less then 50 then there are 49 to chose from including the number 50 would be 50 choices so I think it would be 1/49 + 1/50

Comment: For tuesday player if the answer is "yes" then the numbers $51,52,\dots,100$ are still candidates. These are the numbers $>50$ and there are $50$ such numbers!

Comment: My former comment only concerns a mistake in counting. Much more severe is the fact that you are completely wrong in adding up both probabilities. What is your reason to do that? Try it out on the same situation where $100$ is replaced by $4$ and $50$ is replaced by $2$. According to your reasoning and without repairing the discount mistake mentioned in my former comment your probability would be $1/1+1/2>1$. According to your reasoning with repairing the former discount it would be $1/2+1/2=1$ (so certainty that "tuesday" will guess well). Absurdity in both cases.

Comment: You are free to react or not, and I respect that freedom. But I use the freedom to speak out that it disappoints me that you do not react on my comments. This answer is here for a week now with a downvote on it that is not justified (I am not saying that you are the downvoter). Sad.

Comment: This is why universities like the uw madison suck ! The professors are never around to teach such advanced math ..questions like this ..a contest problem never taught. I appreciate your answer and wish i could understand it . I didnt downvote and will try to upvote

Comment: An example of the ' part i dont get '.. for tuesdays question " is the number greater then 50 ?" That effectively splits the interval in half ? I dont think it will As in if answer is no then 1-50 must be chosen , and if yes its 51-100 but thats only 49 numbers right ??!

Comment: If you ask for printing e.g. the pages numbered 8-11 then the printer gives you the pages 8,9,10,11. So 4 in total. This number equals 11-8+1 and not 11-8 as you seem to think. Note that 100-51+1 equals 50.

Comment: Ah i thought that at first ! Should have went with my intuition . So yes its 1/50 im convinced of that now

Comment: Whats left unclear to me is i get if  monday question got answer yes , u would have to pick 1 number ..that being 57 ..out of 100 so its 1/100..OR ( which means a plus sign not multiply as in And ) choosing the 1 out of 99 numbers but why did u multiply by 99/100 what does that mean ?

Comment: If $M$ denotes the event that monday's contestant wins and the probability on this is denotes as $P(M)$ then $P(M)=P(M\text{ and }W=57)+P(M \text{ and }W\neq57)$. This shows the plus sign you mention. Both terms must be calculated and it is obvious that $P(M\text{ and }W=57)=P(W=57)=\frac1{100}$. The second term is calculated on base of the rule that $P(A\text{ and }B)=P(A\mid B)P(B)$ where $P(A\mid B)$ denotes the probability on $A$ *under condition that event $B$ occurs.* Before going on let me first ask: are you familiar with that rule?

Comment: I was taught P(A/B) was probability A without B occuring ?

Comment: That is something else. $A/B$ is the event/set $A\cap B^{\complement}$. But $P(A\mid B)$ is the probability of $A$ under the condition that $B$ occurs. No $/$ here but $|$. It is defined as $P(A\cap B)/P(B)$.

Comment: So the 1/99 is when the number is not 57 and that means there are now 99 numbers to chose right ? What is the 99/100 ?

Comment: Correct. $\frac{99}{100}$ is the probability that the number is not 57, so is the probability that mondays  contestant comes in that situation.

Comment: No i said 1/99 is choosing 1 out of 99 numbers since if answer is no there are then only 99 numbers . I am stuck on why u multiply 99/100 times that

Comment: On that part (1/99 since only 99 numbers are left as candidates ) I answered with "correct". It is the situation where 57 fall off as candidate.  It must be multiplied with 99/100 because there is a probability of 99/100 that this (I.e. 57 is false) happens.

Comment: Ah i think i see ..u mean the chance mondays question was no and thus means it was not 57 therby making it a probability of 99/100 which is it NOT being 57 ( being any of the 99 out of 100 numbers )

Comment: Indeed. The probability that monday contestant received answer "no" on his first question is $99/100$. This event is actually the event $\{W\neq57\}$ (the winning number is not $57$).

Comment: So its 1/99 that the number is picked AND the probability that the number 57 was not chosen to begin with ( at the initial start of game ) the ' AND' part means multiply (X) ..right ?

Comment: Indeed "and" corresponds with multiplication, but care is needed. If $A$ and $B$ are independent then $P(A\text{ and }B)=P(A)\times P(B)$ but if they are not then conditional probabilities come in. See my edit.

Comment: Now i think it is crystal clear ! And to think this problem and others of ' contest caliber ' NEVER get properly adressed in the ' formal ' school system ! A uw madison professor for example would limit thier scope in teaching a lecture on probality to only the book questions ! Only problems that the ' class ' study and even then as far as one - on -one 'office hours' they were never around and if they were , they would be flooded with the mediocre minded students asking thier mediocre questions . What a waste ( i tried a semester there )

Comment: Nice to hear that it is crystal clear. The greatest reward for a teacher is the understanding of his pupil. If this answer meets your needs then accept it. Good luck with your study of probability theory and do not allow yourself to be demotivated by **anything** (including professors).

Comment: probability is one favorites. Professors should give more then lectures and grades, if they are truly absorbed with math they should be available 24 /7 like i am to my pupils as a private tutor . Whats nice is this website IS open 24/7 !! And having acess to good teachers and overall 24 /7  math nerds lol .thanks again

Comment: Nice to hear that it is crystal clear. The greatest reward for a teacher is the understanding of his pupil. If this answer meets your needs then accept it. Good luck with your study of probability theory and do not allow yourself to be demotivated by anything (including professors). – drhab Aug 30 '18 at 7:15 awesome motivation as a math coach !!

Comment: $\cdots\cdots$;-)